# IIS local website. Can't load .js files

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, iis, .net-core

I created a simple application with angular 2 cli and .net core application which works perfectly when I run it with visual studio.  When I published the website and tried it with IIS the following errors are occurred:
[image]

[image: This is what the files look like in wwwroot directory but they are not loaded]

[image]

What can be the possible problems?
Thanks.

Comment: Your absolute path requesting those js files is incorrect

Answer (score 2):

Be sure to add the middleware UseStaticFiles to your startup.cs. This allows the files in the wwwroot folder to be servable.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    app.UseStaticFiles();
}
```